# Custom select box drop down inside a table cell in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have kept a Custom select box in a Table Td cell, which when clicked opens a list of two custom options. Adding a row to the table creates another instance of the same Custom select box whose functionality is same as above.

```
<div class="multiselect">
                <div class="InternetselectBox" id="Connectivity_COld9_InternetFacilityDiv_1" onclick="showInternetLocationCheckboxes(this)">

                  <select class="location_select" style="color: #666;" id="Connectivity_COld9_InternetFacility_1">
                    <option value="0"> 2 Location Selected</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="overSelect"></div>
                </div>

              <div class="MultiSelect_checkboxes InternetMultiSelect" id="Connectivity_COld9_MultiSelect_checkboxes_1" style="display: block;">

                    <label for="Connectivity_COld9_InternetFacilityCHK_1_1">
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="Connectivity_COld9_InternetFacilityCHK_1_1" name="lineup[]" onclick="InternetDynamicCheckboxCount(this)">

                      TCO
                    </label>
                    <label for="Connectivity_COld9_InternetFacilityCHK_1_2">
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="Connectivity_COld9_InternetFacilityCHK_1_2" name="lineup[]" onclick="InternetDynamicCheckboxCount(this)">

                      MEPS
                    </label>
                </div>
              </div>
```

The issue is, when I click on the select box, and scroll the page or that particular div(table div), the drop down menu also moves along with the scrolling direction. I have a little bit of confusion with using Css style of Position 
[image]

And when I add row and scroll down, the drop down also moves along.[image]

Help me in resolving this issue. I want a drop down to appear just when I click the drop down and not move when I scroll down or up.

I tried to use css property position: relative to the drop down. But, it displaces or expands other Td of the same row. I do not need this.

Any css class needs to be added. Let me know. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of CSS are you currently applying to the drop-down?

Comment: CSS style of Postion : Absolute and Relative. Using absolute position, the content of the select box moves along the scrolling direction and using Relative position, it displaces the other table element which is highly not what I wanted.

Comment: could you post the CSS you're using so I can play around w/ it a little, see what happens?

Comment: For dropdown:     border: 1px #dadada solid;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 70px!important;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;  position: absolute!important;
    width: 300px;

Comment: For select box div :     position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 29px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;